# Why does Moa's 3D/mini form look different from her 2D/full-size form?

Tags: show-by-rock

In *Show By Rock!!*, most of the characters look pretty similar between their full-size 2D-animated versions and their miniature 3D-animated versions. However, Moa is weird. In 2D, she looks like this:

[image: 2D Moa]

And in 3D, she looks like this:

[image: 3D Moa]

For some reason, she's black-colored in 3D-mode but not in 2D-mode. I get that her animal is a sheep, and that black sheep are a thing, but why is there this disparity between the two depictions of her?

Answer (score 2):

This might be just a speculation.

Moa's myumon form came first. It was part of original [Show By Rock mobile game](http://showbyrock.com/game/). As you point out, it is based on [black-skinned sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffolk_sheep). As the art style is heavily stylized and the sprites are mostly static in game, it doesn't feel wrong.

But then, Show By Rock anime happens and Plasmagica becomes main cast. And for that the characters get standard anime style. But in that style, black skin like that would look jarring and most people would probably dislike it. So the producers decided to just go with plain anime girl with pink hair. But because the 3D is primarilly based on original myumon forms, they had to keep her black skin there.

Actually, all characters loose their animal traits when moving from myumon style to anime style. Cyan, Retoree and Chuchu all have animal-snouted faces as myumons but "human" faces in anime. Same with ShinganCrimsonz.

Also, did you notice producer Maple is NOT an egg in human form? Shocking, right?